# Crashed: AVAudioSession Notify Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crash. Is that AVFAudio native SDK issue or i missed something should to be handled?

Please have a look at crashlytics screenshot for more info.
[image]

I initialized the AVAudioSession by calling:

```
- (BOOL)prepareAudioSession {

BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error: nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"deactivationError");
}

success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 
withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"setCategoryError");
}

success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: nil];
if (!success) {
   NSLog(@"activationError");
}

return success;

}
```

and then I call [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs] to check for the number of bluetooth connected devices

Comment: This looks like wrong management of memory. It's really hard to say what it is without an example of code. You may be trying to access a value that is already removed by the ARC. Can you post a piece of code?

Comment: Thanks @juniorgarcia for your help. I have posted my code in the original question. BTW I couldn't reproduce that crash but I saw it on fabric. Also, I used instruments to figure out the problem but didn't find any memory leaks.

Comment: Look at the backtrace and find the last frame in your code.   That'll be the trigger of the crash.  If there is none of your code in the stack trace, then you're configuring AV in a way that triggers a crash.  Without more evidence, hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace, look likes you subscribe for KVO changes or some notifications, like AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification or MPVolumeViewWirelessRouteActiveDidChangeNotification, but your object(listener) is released without removeObserver/unsubscribing.

In iOS 9 or later it is no longer necessary for an NSNotificationCenter observer to un-register itself when being deallocated. So I would recommend to checkout KVOs.

Comment: Thanks, ilnal_al. But I initialized the AVAudioSession in appDelegate.m and I don't observe for any notifications or KVO changes.